# how to drop user in mysql with incorrect host.?

Tags: mysql

I have user **test** with host `192.168.1.1';`

I want to drop this user with an incorrect host.

I tried to type:
DROP USER `'test'@'192.168.1.1';;'` 
but this command is wrong.

How can I drop this user?

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the apostrophe in host.

```
DROP USER 'test'@'192.168.1.1\';;';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do first a

```
 SELECT Host,User from mysql.user WHERE user = 'test';
```

And check the host(s) for this user

And then make

```
DROP USER 'test'@'192.168.1.1';
```

if the host is `192.168.1.1`

If you have really a tick in your hist entry you must use an escape \ character before the inner apostrophe like `'test'@'192.168.1.1\';;'`